# downloading 14.04 desktop onto a USB, Is this the file I need to run the OS?

Tags: usb-installation

I downloaded ubuntu 14.04 desktop-amd64.iso onto a USB because there was not enough room on the dvd. Is this the file I need to run the OS? It still keeps asking me to burn image to a dvd.  I need the steps to install and run the OS.

Comment: Are you attempting to perform a dual boot?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Answer (score 0):

- Acquire the correct Ubuntu installation files ('the ISO')
- Put Ubuntu onto your USB flash drive using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- Configure your computer to boot from USB flash drive and boot from it
- Try Ubuntu or install it to your hard drive.